# "predicting" or "prediction of"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, gerunds

What is the difference between "can be used for **prediction of** user behaviour" and "can be used for **predicting** user behaviour"?

I like the second version more since it's shorter and without a postposition but what is the difference in the meaning between these two phrases if any?

Answer (score 1):

***for prediction of user behavior**

is just what it is: even though it seems logical, it is **an awkward construct, not used by native speakers**, and that is caused by the lack of "the" in front or "prediction."

See e.g. at Google Books (not vanilla Books)

[for prediction of user behavior](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22any+kind+of+applications%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22for+prediction+of+user+behavior%22)
About 1 results

which is written by a non-native speaker.

"for the prediction of user behavior" 
10 results

is definitely better, but the best is:

["for predicting user behavior"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22any%20kind%20of%20applications%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22for%20predicting%20user%20behavior%22)
About 55 results

Answer (score 0):

I have a prolix friend whom I proofread, and I ask him to imagine he is going to be billed per word by the Customs and Excess. "For predicting" pays less tax than "for the prediction of".